# EhCache RMI replication show different number of elements in two instances

Tags: java, replication, rmi, ehcache

We can't find another way to test cache replication between two instances of server except run stress test on nginx address, that 
distributes the requests by load between two instances. After test working finished, we check the number of elements in each cache using java-melody browser interface on both instances. And there is difference in cache between two instances. Can somebody tell is that normal behavior of ehcache? If no what solution can we use to fix that problem?

P.S.: In case using single requests cache replication works fine.

Configuration Instance1:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">
  <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=host1, port=7571, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

 <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual,  
        rmiUrls=//host1:7572/ClientLink_ID|//host1:7572/ClientLink_MainID|//host1:7572/ClientLink_SubID|.../>
```

Configuration Instance2:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">
 <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=host1, port=7572, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

 <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual,  
        rmiUrls=//host1:7571/ClientLink_ID|//host1:7571/ClientLink_MainID|//host1:7571/ClientLink_SubID|.../>

</ehcache>
```

Example of cache config:

```
<cache name="ClientLink_ID"
           eternal="false"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"
           timeToIdleSeconds="600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="900"
           statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="none"/>
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
    </cache>
```